# Assembly printing system date

Tags: date, assembly, x86, masm

I have a problem with printing system date because of cx register size. How can it be solved without any big changes?

```
title casadatum

zas     segment stack
        db      256 dup(?) 
zas ends

strsize EQU 64

dat segment
   print db 'Current System Date is : $'
   date db  'dd:mm:rrrr$'
   nl db 10,13,'$' 
dat ends

code segment
                assume cs:code, ss:zas, ds:dat

get_date proc
          mov ah,2ah
          int 21h
          mov al,dl
          call convert
          mov [bx],ax
          mov al,dh
          call convert
          mov [bx+3],ax
          mov al,cx
          call convert
          mov [bx+6],ax     

        ret
        endp          


convert proc
        push dx
        mov ah,0
        mov dl,10
        div dl
        or ax, 3030h
        pop dx
        ret 
        endp    


start:

        mov ax, seg dat
        mov ds,ax

        LEA BX, date
        CALL GET_date

        lea dx,print
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

        lea dx,date
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h

koniec:
        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h

code ends
        end start
```

Comment: Divide `cx` by 100 and print the quotient and the remainder after each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this part of your code

```
mov al,cx
call convert
mov [bx+6],ax
```

with these instructions

```
mov al,100
xchg ax,cx
div cl
mov ch,ah
call convert
mov [bx+6],ax
mov al,ch
call convert
mov [bx+8],ax
```